# Prefix Matching in C++

Tags: c++, regex, string, stl, substring

**Problem:**

Let's say I have a list of prefixes:

```
[p1, p2, p3, ... pn] //Prefix List (strings)
```

I want to know if a string 'target' has any of the aforementioned prefixes.

Naive solution example:

```
bool contains_prefix(std::string target, vector<std::string> &prefixes)
{
    for (const auto& prefix : prefixes)
    {
       if (target.compare(0, prefix.length(), prefix)
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::string> prefixes{"car" , "auto" , "biscuits"};

bool test = contains_prefix("automobile", prefixes); //returns true
test = contains_prefix("biscu", prefixes); //returns false
test = contains_prefix("v", prefixes); //returns false (obviously)
```

So, this naive solution has the obvious shortfall that it must iterate through every item in the list.

**Is there a faster way to implement prefix matching of this type?**

**Thing's Ive tried:**

**1.** I tried creating a compare object to be used with an std::set, but sets require strict weak ordering (equality is tested via a>b and a'<'b , both must be false). So the std::compare() function does not work in this case since checking if one string is a prefix of another is an asymmetric relationship.

**2.** I can implement using Regexes, but this doesn't solve the problem of having to iterate through every element.

**3.** Any data structure that hashes doesn't work for pattern based matching.

Comment: try a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many possible prefixes do you plan to have? If it is less than 50 then I don't think there is anything to optimize.

If you use any optimization do a performance measurements to make sure that you are gaining anything. More complex solution will be slower for small number of prefixes.

The easiest solution is use of tree and this is implemented in `set`, so this should do the trick (it has `o(log n)` complexity):

```
// needed since we want longer prefixes before 
// the shorter one with same begging
class StrCmpRevAlphaLongerFirst {
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const {
        return !std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                             b.begin(), b.end(),
                                             std::greater_equal<char>()
                                            );
    }
};

using PrefixSet = std::set<std::string, StrCmpRevAlphaLongerFirst>;

bool contains_prefix(const std::string& target, const PrefixSet &prefixes)
{
    auto it = prefixes.lower_bound(target);
    return it->length() <= target.length() 
        && std::equal(it->begin(), it->end(), target.begin());
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/hoskfQxh6nr2BLq7

In special cases I think it is possible to achieve constant time (by using hash functions). For example if you have lots of prefixes which length are limited you can use `std::unordered_set`.

```
class PrefixMatcher {
public:
    PrefixMatcher(const std::unordered_set<std::string> &prefixes)
        : m_prefixes(prefixes)
    {
         for (const auto &s : m_prefixes) {
              m_lengths.insert(s.length());
         }
    }

    bool machesPrefix(const std::string& target) const {
         for (auto length : m_lengths) {
             if (target.length() < length) {
                 continue;
             }
             std::string prefix{ target.begin(), target.begin() + length };
             if (m_prefixes.count(prefix) == 1) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_set<std::string> m_prefixes;
    std::set<size_t> m_lengths;    
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/fXnO3GHimtram6Lo

Above solution has constant time complexity if prefixes have limited number of possible lengths.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on, what is your goal.

If you have a lot of prefixes and just one 'target', than your code is optimal.

But if you have a lot of 'targets', than you might want to consider creating a smarter structure than just a list of prefixes. I would recommend using prefix tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Building the structure might take some time, but if use have a lot of 'targets', it will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using std::string;
using std::regex;
using std::cout;

bool contains_prefix(const string& target, const string& prefixes)
{
    return std::regex_match(target, regex(prefixes));
}

int main()
{
    string target = "automobile";
    if (contains_prefix(target, "(car)(.*)|(auto)(.*)|(biscuits)(.*)"))
        std::cout << "The target has prefix.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "The target has no prefix.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If you have many prefixes, you may consider converting them in a single regular expression string.